# Autocomplete in dynamically added textbox

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

how to add the auto-complete in this dynamically added Textbox?
i have used this way **$('#se').autocomplete();**, but not getting that.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () 
    {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          '<input type="text" placeholder="Role" name="Role' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" > <input type="text"
          placeholder="Search" name="search' + counter + 
          '" id="se" value="" > <input type="hidden"  name="search' + counter + 
          '" id="se' + counter + '" value="" >');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        $('#se').autocomplete();
        counter++;
    });

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="form-inline control-group">
        <%= text_field_tag('roles', nil,:id => 'textbox1')%>
        <%= text_field_tag('search', nil,:id => 'se')%>
        <%=hidden_field_tag(:id_search, value = "")%>
        <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude, you are reusing the same ID I guess... Duplicate IDs are not supported in HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were issues with string concatination and selection in your code:-

Main thing is `$('#se' + counter).autocomplete({source: availableTags});` you weren't attaching counter here. And there was no source too. In the example i have just attached hummy source, it could be static source or ajax inyour case.

See [Doc](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for more details...

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wmBmR/)

Try this:-

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {
   var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

   newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" placeholder="Role" name="Role' +   counter +   '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value=""> <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search' + counter + '" id="se' + counter + '" > <input type="hidden"  name="search' + counter + '" value="" >');
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    $('#se' + counter).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
counter++;
 });
```

For more clarity you should use jquery element constructor and build the lements for more readeability [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wdr3/)

```
 var roleInput = $('<input/>',{
        type:'text',
        placeholder:'Role',
        name:'Role'+counter,
        id:'textbox' + counter
    });

    var searchInput = $('<input/>',{
        type:'text',
        placeholder:'search',
        name:'search'+counter,
        id:'se' + counter
    });

    var hidd=$('<input/>',{
        type:'hidden',
        name:'searchhid'+counter,
        id:'searchhid' + counter
    });


    newTextBoxDiv.append(roleInput).append(searchInput).append(hidd);
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    $('#se' + counter).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    counter++;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Here you are using the arrays of strings, but i am taking that values directly from server. so?

Comment: You need to set the Ajax data source if it is live fetch else get the data and supply it in source check this:- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: i cannot use else case, because here the huge data will be used

Comment: Ok. You can look at the doc to see which one suits ur need. I guess i fixed the issue that u had in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

IDS should always be unique... since your are generating input with same id.. your HTML becomes invalid (though it works).. one way to make it work is to changes the ids to class...

```
 <%= text_field_tag('search', nil,:class=> 'se')%>

...<input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search' + counter + '" class="se" value="" >...
```

and use class selector for autocomplete,

```
$('.se').autocomplete();
```